# Groovy: Get XML Tag first level

Tags: xml, groovy

How can it be achieved to get the "first-level" tag names of an XML file using Groovy.
Supposed we have following XML:

```html
<records>
  <first>
    <car>
      <id>378932</id>
    </car>
  </first>
  <second>
    <foo>
      <car>
       <name>audi</name>
      </car>
    </foo>
  </second>
</records>
```

...I want to get "first" and "second" as a result of my script.

I am parsing the XML using XMLSlurper:

```html
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse("test.xml");
```

I tried with the depthFirst() method, but this delivers all the available nodes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be:

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse("test.xml")

xml.children().each { node -> 
  println node.name()
}
```

where both the `xml` and `node` variables are of type:

[groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/NodeChild.html)

The above prints:

```
first
second
```

or if you want the first level node names as a list:

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse("test.xml")

def firstLevelNames = xml.children()*.name()
println firstLevelNames
```

which prints:

```
[first, second]
```

Answer (score 0):

I can achieve this using the following statement:

```
println xml.'*'*.name()
```